# DXmessage box Shows error while runing inside the thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

DxMessageBox Shows error while running inside the thread shows the following error
"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

```
  DXMessageBox.Show("No data to be with selected parameters",  messageTitle);
```

if it is windows message box it will work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke your code from dispatcher

```
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
               DispatcherPriority.Send,
               new Action(delegate()
               {
                   //your code
               }));
```

Comment: Yes. Actually DXMessageBox will be run in a different thread. so that error was occurred. We prevent this by using Dispatcher